# How to make user remake the function if the answer is not correct

Tags: javascript

I want to give user an question. Go to the left, right or continue straight. If user wrotes 'straight' in javascript `prompt` method. The other 2 methods are false - Game over. When is Game over I want user to make this story again.

```
var prompt = propmt("Where will you go? Left, right or continue straight?");
if (prompt === "Left") {
  confirm("Game over, the tigers will eat you!");
} else if (where === "Straight") {
  confirm("You've won!");
} else {
  confirm("Game over, you've fallen to the river!");
}
```

if gameOver than i want to user retry the story.
Thanks!

link to JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/grqxc5kr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
function game() {
  while (true) {
    var prompt = prompt("Where will you go? Left, right or continue straight?");

    if (prompt === "Left") {
      confirm("Game over, the tigers will eat you!");
    } else if (prompt === "Straight") {
      confirm("You've won!");
      return
    } else {
      confirm("Game over, you've fallen to the river!");
    }
  }
}
```

This is not the idomatic way of doing it (note the while(true)), but this will get you to your end result.

A better way of doing it:

```
function game() {
  var prompt = ""
  while (prompt != "Left" || prompt != "Straight") {
    prompt = prompt("Where will you go? Left, right or continue straight?");
    if (prompt === "Left") {
      confirm("Game over, the tigers will eat you!");
    } else if (prompt === "Straight") {
      confirm("You've won!");
    } else {
      confirm("Game over, you've fallen to the river! Let's play again!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @manonthemat, while true does work in javascript. Unsure what you mean by "like this"

Comment: Thank you. This works! I've learned somethink new and easier to do! Thanks

Comment: @william.taylor.09 I've meant the "while true" without the parenthesis. Since you've edited the code, I've removed that comment. I personally would also use switch/case here instead of if/else, but it's not necessary to make it right.

Comment: Very valid point. In my haste to answer, I gave a sloppy solution. Edited my answer to add another option without while(true).

Answer (score 1):

Nest it in a loop.

Here are also a few stylistic opinions.

You might want to rename your variable "prompt" to what it actually represents, which is the return value of the prompt function call, or in simpler terms it's user input.

In your conditionals you're only comparing the value of that variable to potential choices. This is a good place to replace the if/else if/else with a switch/case block. It's also easier to extend would you choose to have different actions based on the user's input in the future. Not only does this potentially increase development speed, but in most languages this results also in a slight performance increase.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion will do what you're looking for:

```
function getDirection(){
    var input = prompt("Where will you go? Left, right or continue straight?");
    if (input === "Left") {
        confirm("Game over, the tigers will eat you!");
        getDirection();
    } else if (input === "Straight") {
        confirm("You've won!");
    } else {
        confirm("Game over, you've fallen to the river!");
        getDirection();
  }
}
getDirection();
```